# sql server log messages abouts logins

Tags: sql-server

After i logged in to SQL server using management studio i opened the log and i got a million messages showing

> Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used
>   with Windows authentication. [CLIENT: 222.186.61.5]

or

> Login failed for user 'sa'. Reason: Password did not match that for
>   the login provided. [CLIENT: 222.186.61.5]

or

> Login failed for user 'kisadmin'. Reason: Could not find a login
>   matching the name provided. [CLIENT: 222.186.61.5]

or

> Login failed for user 'wwo'. Reason: Could not find a login matching
>   the name provided. [CLIENT: 104.217.216.169]

I have many more logs for many users and IP's which first appeared *10/6/2015 8:06:19 PM* (and i have them everyday). Are these messages showing that i have been cyber attacked ?

Comment: Well those are just the failed attempts. Hopefully there aren't any successful ones

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you see is a set of failed login tries, so, you can know for sure that someone tries to hack your database. Unfortunately, if there were successful attempts, then people might have read some data from your part. You need to kill all active connections and change the port you are using for your database.

Also, it would be nice if you would think about how people were able to try to log in to your database. Are you having by accident any public information about where your database server is (like error messages, for example)?

Comment: i am using standard port for sql 1433, i have private firewall rules that are configured only for my local network.

Comment: Those IP addresses look likely to be from an external network.  It seems your private firewall is misconfigured.

Comment: @NikolaLozanovski, those are failed login attempts. I would not be happy to see failed login attempts at the database server.